# Php Mysql Table Search/List

Tags: c#, php, mysql

Solved my problem,

I was trying to figure out how to select a column from the nth row, put simply.
I've done that by doing the following,

Php->

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$query = mysql_num_rows($sql);

for ($i=0; i<$numRows; $i++) {

  //ETC
}
```

Comment: Quite a lot of blanks to fill.. You should research each section alone such as SQL queries, how to interact with databases and string manipulation functions. As these are basic to PHP / C#.

Comment: Doing that now, I'm just trying to figure out how to select a column from the nth row.

Comment: Figured it out, should've read up before posting this, apologies to all.

Comment: You should select all the rows with one query and iterate through them that way `SELECT * FROM fooTable` etc..